Angular - Home page is quickly displayed before current page
I have an Angular website hosted on AWS S3 with SSR activated. It is available on this URL: https://goodproperties.r3tests.net
When I go to https://goodproperties.r3tests.net/offer/1 , I expect to see the content of this page directly, however, it quickly shows the content of the homepage before (which I do not want) before showing the appropriate content. How to fix this ?
https://goodproperties.r3tests.net/offer/1
(Quickly show this, it should not)

(Then show this, it should only show this)


Could be due to SSR, could you replicate this issue using minimal code on a stackblitz for checking, or github repo?

@NarenMurali Yes, the most updated code is available on the debug branch https://github.com/rragoomundun/good-properties/tree/feature/debug
